# Stop JSON code from injecting into gutenburg classic block

Tags: block-editor, json

How can I stop gutenburg from injecting JSON code when I move classic blocks around in the page? See screencast here:   https://www.screencast.com/t/nYof6w6qExg

This is fresh copy of wordpress. It's been doing this at least for a year now.

Comment: Your screencast link doesn’t work. Can you just share an example of the HTML in the body of your question?

Comment: Sorry, I updated it now.